# Why is this glass getting blown out?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, glass, noise-reduction

Ok I have a lot of glass in my scene but these shards I have on the floor, regardless of denoising settings or otherwise, that do not appear clear but rather get blown out into white.

[image]

Denoise settings, yet they are still grainy and blown out:

[image]

The other glass, like on the eyes, are clean and have reflections. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Issue is this happened with no denoise at all

Comment: Could the normals be facing the wrong way? If you Recalculate Normals it might fix the issue.